# Set bubble size according to categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data, bubble-chart

Keep in mind, I am very new to R.
I have a dataset from a public opinion survey, and would like to represent the answers through a bubble chart, though the data is categorical, not numeric.

From dataset "Arab4" I have question/variable "Q713" with all of the observations coded as 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 as the response options. I would like to plot the bubbles (stacked on top of one another by "country") with the size of the bubble corresponding to the percent of the vote share that answer got. For example, if 49% of respondents in Israel voted for option 1 under question "Q", then the bubble size would represent 49% and be situated above the Israel category label with the color of the bubble corresponding to the response type (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5).

I have the following code, giving me a blank chart, and I know to eventually use the "points" command with more specifications. 
What I need help with is defining the radius of the circles from the data I have.

```
    plot(Arab4$Country, Arab4$Q713, type= "n", xlab = FALSE, ylab=FALSE)
    points(Arab4$country, Arab4$q713)
```

Here is some dput from the data set

```
dput(Arab4$q713[1:50])

structure(c(3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 
2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3), labels = structure(c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 98, 99), .Names = c("Promoting democracy", "Promoting economic 
development", 
"Resolving the Arab-Israeli conflict", "Promoting women’s rights", 
"The US should not get involved", "Don't know (Do not read)", 
"Decline to answer (Do not read)")), class = "labelled")
```

Any ideas would help! Thanks!

Comment: If you could run dput(A) or dput(Arab4), depending on which one is your dataset, and paste the result, which would give your data structure and content, that would make it easier to respond. If the datasets are very large, just do it on a subset (like dput(A[1:10,], for example).

Comment: Can I suggest that a stacked bar or area chart might be a better visualisation for this use case (proportions of categories).

Comment: @neilfws I agree. Unfortunately, I have been asked to not use a bar or pie chart, and the data is not over time so the stacked area probably wouldn't work.

Comment: Can we please have the structure of `A` too.

Comment: @neilfws sorry, A is Arab4, I just forgot to change it in the later code. They are the same dataset.

Comment: OK, but there are no countries or percentages of respondents in that data, so we can't generate the chart from that.

Comment: @neilfws the countries are a separate variable in the dataset (Arab4$Country). As for the percentages, that is what I'm trying to figure out. Is there a way to have the bubble size represent the percentage of the vote share for each response category within the q713 column

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, this really is not a bubble chart as you only have 2 dimensions and the size of the circle does not add anything (other than perhaps visual appeal).  But with that disclaimer, here is one approach to what I think you are trying to achieve.  This requires the ggplot2 and reshape2 libraries.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# create simulated data
dat <- data.frame(Egypt=sample(c(1:5), 20), Libya=sample(c(1:5),20))
# tabulate
dat.tab <- apply(dat, 2, table)
dat.long <- melt(dat.tab)
colnames(dat.long) <- c("Response", "Count", "Country")
ggplot(dat.long, aes(x=Country, y=Count, color=Country)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size=Count))
```

**EDIT**  Here is another approach, using the data manipulation tools of the dplyr package to get you all the way to proportions:

```
# using dat from above again
dat.long <- melt(dat)
colnames(dat.long) <- c("Country", "Response")

dat.tab <- dat.long %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  count(Response) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n))

ggplot(dat.tab, aes(x=Country, y=prop, color=Country)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size=prop))
```

You will need to do a little additional work to remove unwanted values (98, 99) if they are truly unwanted.

hth.